# Sidekiq keep shutting down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I'm just wondering if someone had same issue with ***sidekiq*** like me..
Using rails app(updated) and 2 env on different instance(prod,dev), but on prod ***sidekiq*** just keep shutting down after several hours, and dev is working just fine.

- Sidekiq log checked (no error)
- Redis server log checked (no error)
- Prod log checked (no error)
- Sidekiq job is fine

So I'm wondering where or what i missed.
Appreciate any help with that..

Comment: Linux? Might check system logs to see if OOM Killer killed it. That would result in zero entries in your other logs.

Comment: I used this for finding OOM Killer.. `egrep -i 'killed process' /var/log/logs.log` for logs and there is nothing.. and also `dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process'`